# How to scale ImageView width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

This is my layout file

```
<LinearLayout ...
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/feed_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/image_content_description" />
```

But `ImageView` width does not **match parent** width. (width is image source width)

Image Source loaded Lazy-loading from url.

How to scale the width of image view regadless image source ?

I want

**Width = match(or fill) parent.**

**Height = auto-scaled**

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType. use android:scaleType attribute

Comment: give appropriate  weight to width and make height as wrap-contain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this in two ways:

1. If your image is larger than the ImageView you can use xml only

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
   ```
2. If your image is smaller than the ImageView

   ```
   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
   ```

With the second option you have to measure the width and height of the image and set the height of the ImageView in your code, according to the actual width of the image view (same ratio).

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use `android:scaletype="fitXY"` property of imageview

   2.default Android will scale your image down to fit the ImageView, maintaining the aspect ratio. However, make sure you're setting the image to the ImageView using android:src="..." rather than android:background="...". src= makes it scale the image maintaining aspect ratio, but background= makes it scale and distort the image to make it fit exactly to the size of the ImageView. (You can use a background and a source at the same time though, which can be useful for things like displaying a frame around the main image, using just one ImageView.)

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to fit the image in view use android:scaleType="fitXY"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with this, create new AspectRatioImageView that extends imageView:

```
public class AspectRatioImageView extends ImageView {

    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AspectRatioImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        Drawable drw = getDrawable();
        if (null == drw || drw.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        } else {
            int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = width * drw.getIntrinsicHeight() / drw.getIntrinsicWidth();
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your layout xml use :

```
<my.app.AspectRatioImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ar_imageview"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/idImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

calculate the height according to the aspect ratio that you want

```
    Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int height = (display.getWidth() * 9) /16; // in this case aspect ratio 16:9

    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.idImage);
    image.getLayoutParams().height = height;
```